# How to shorten code?

Tags: python

I have a dict, I need to check all values through my function(this function can not be changed).
code:

```
if func(arg, dict['a']) and func(arg, dict['b']) and func(arg, dict['c']) and func(arg, dict['d']): 
    pass
```

How to shorten if statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all(func(arg, my_dict[k]) for k in my_dict):
  ...
```

Don't use `dict` as a variable name.

Comment: `for c in dict` would be a big improvement here, as the OP specifically notes he wants to check all values in the dict.  (Although thefourtheye's solution is even better, at least under Python 3).

Comment: @LennartRegebro - OP's current code does not check all values, but will short-circuit on first value that is False.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: Well, duh.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `all` function like this

```
if all(func(arg, value) for value in myDict.values()):
    ...
```

**Note:** Never use builtin type names as variable names. In your case, `dict` is a builtin type and function's name. Thats why I have `myDict`

**Sample Run**

```
def func(arg, value):
    return value

myDict = {}.fromkeys(list("abcd"), True)
if all(func("", value) for value in myDict.values()):
    print "All TRUE"
```

**Output**

```
All TRUE
```

Comment: Why the contorted code with `not any`? `all` will short-circuit on the first False value also.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Oops. Yeah. I am removing that

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, the functional approach. (may be better to use imap instead of map for Python2)

```
from functools import partial
if all(map(partial(func, arg), my_dict.values()):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code and most solutions using `all` or `any` will stop evaluating entries in your dict as soon as the first False value is found (this feature is called "short-circuiting"). If you *must* call `func` for every value in the dict, and if `func` returns True or False (i.e., you are not relying on Python's bool interpretation of non-bool types), then you can use `sum`:

```
if sum(func(arg, my_dict[k]) for k in my_dict) == len(my_dict):
```

This makes use of the Python equivalence of `True` with 1 and `False` with 0.

If `func` returns non-bool values, then wrap the calls to `func` with `bool`:

```
if sum(bool(func(arg, my_dict[k])) for k in my_dict) == len(my_dict):
```

Comment: Or being slightly wasteful you can just add extra `[]` inside `all` to make the argument a list comprehension.